# Play file with vlc using path from clipboard

Tags: vlc

So my scenario is that I've copied an http link (that I want to stream with vlc player) to the clipboard. I would like to write a simple script that plays the file located at the path on the clipboard. I've already tried

pbpaste | VLC -

pbpaste outputs the contents of the clipboard to stdout and "VLC -" attempts to play what's on stdout, so I was hoping VLC would pick up the path, read it, and then fetch the file to play, but apparently it expects an actual byte stream when you pipe things to it, not a string filepath. I've tried something similar on windows that failed so I don't think this is OS-specific

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
sh4d0w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
LOC=$(pbpaste); vlc -vvv $LOC
```

It should work as long as you've copied the "http://" as well. In fact, it will work for any string as described in [this manual chapter](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html)

Comment: on second thought, this one-liner should also work, too:
    vlc -vvv $(pbpaste)

Comment: tried this on my windows machine and it failed. it picked up the $ as a normal string and tried to play a file in the pwd with filename $(paste.exe). i'll try a bit later on my mac though

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were using linux. I think mac uses bash, but I'm not sure, but try that one-liner in the terminal on mac, it might work. Are you scripting using batch on windows?

Comment: I love you sir, def worked on my mac. I was just putting stuff in the command line on windows, I'm aware now that that was silly but I'm not too concerned since I really only need this to work with mac.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This works nowadays for the urls that I've been using

```
$url=Get-ClipBoard; $vlc=start-Process -FilePath "vlc" -ArgumentList $url,-f,vlc://quit
```